# Trying to edit page results in (#300) Edit failure, but the changes are saved?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use the js sdk to publish and edit fb pages. This was working fine until I yesterday started to test what would happen in the page editor that I'm building when a user uninstalls the app in FB.

When I reloaded the page in my editor, the js login box showed up and I need to authorize the app again, so it seemed to have worked fine. But then when I tried to publish or update a FB page, it kept getting these errors.

```
code 300    
message "(#300) Edit failure"
type "OAuthException"
```

The funny thing is that the page does get published and the updates are also published on fB itself. So the publishing and updating of the page works fine, but it also produces this error which messes up my script.

```
FB.api('/'+pageTabId+'?access_token='+pageAccessToken, 'post', params, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) { //
        console.log("Error Installing:");
     } else {
        console.log('tab updated');                                                                                          
     }          
});
```

I tried to logout of FB, uninstall the app, remove all cookies and cache. But none of it seems to make a difference.. I had this before, but then it suddenly disappeared. But that doesn't seem to be the case this time.

The "OAuthException" tells me I'm not authorized to make the changes, but how can the changes I make or the page itself possibly get published then?

What would I need to do to make the (#300) Edit failure error disappear?

Comment: I got "(#300) Edit failure" after trying to set page tab custom_image with wrong dimensions (other than 111x74 px).

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, came across this FB bug report https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/255313014574414/